# Error designator in initializer for scalar type

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors, installation

Ok, for a bit of context, I am a graduate student in theoretical physics and for my research I need to play with various modern method to compute Feynman/string integrals. Furthermore, I must say that my knowledge in programming is so far pretty limited to Mathematica (high) and a bit of C/C++ (ok), thus, sorry if my question is a bit naive.

That said, there is a nice [code (FIRE6)](https://bitbucket.org/feynmanIntegrals/fire/src/master/FIRE6/) that I would really like to play with. Any file I am talking about below can be found on this website.  The code is designed to be compatible Linux 64bit, Mac
OS X 10.6 or higher 64bit. My computer is a MacBook pro 1.4 GHz, Quad-Core, with Intel Core i5, so I should be fine fine (For the love of completeness, I am working with Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.59)). So far I performed the

```
make dep
```

operation successfully in my terminal. Then, following the intruction provided [here](https://bitbucket.org/feynmanIntegrals/fire/src/master/README.md), I performed the

```
make
```

operation (you can find the script for the MakeFile [here](https://bitbucket.org/feynmanIntegrals/fire/src/master/FIRE6/poly/Makefile.in)). This outputs me the following error

```
 MyName FIRE6 % sudo make
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make -C ./poly
g++ -O3 -Wall -Wno-strict-aliasing -Wno-narrowing -std=c++11  -I../usr/include -DSMALL_POINT  -DWITH_SNAPPY -DWITH_ZSTD -DWITH_ZLIB -DFSBALLOCATOR_USE_THREAD_SAFE_LOCKING_PTHREAD -fno-builtin-malloc -fno-builtin-calloc -fno-builtin-realloc -fno-builtin-free   -c ../sources/main.cpp
../sources/main.cpp:451:73: error: designator in initializer for
      scalar type 'in_port_t' (aka 'unsigned short')
  ...htons(common::port), {.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, {}};
                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make[1]: *** [main.o] Error 1
make: *** [default] Error 2
```

I copy/paste this error online and unfortunately after many hours I found no working solutions... If it can help, the problematic line seems to be:

```
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr = {AF_INET,  htons(common::port), {.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, {}};
```

in this [code](https://bitbucket.org/feynmanIntegrals/fire/src/master/FIRE6/sources/main.cpp). I want to install this for research purposes, so help would be really appreciated! Also, feel free to explain the solution, I am really curious about what is not working.

**Remark:** The code available on Mac Os since recently, so I would like your advices before contacting the creator, just in the case what I am not understanding is minor.

Comment: That seems odd, designated initializers are not available in c++11.

Comment: Hmmm... I also read this online. However, the code is know to work with '-std=c++11'. I'm a bit confused. See [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1901.07808.pdf) for example.

Comment: It looks to me like the `sockaddr_in` type on your system has an extra member early on. [This thread](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=12684732) seems to corroborate that, though I was unable to find such in actual documentation 

Comment: What I mean to say is that this code doesn't appear at a glance to be fully portable to any system that does add such a member.

Comment: "Vanilla" clang [compiles this just fine](https://wandbox.org/permlink/swyiaZNrcuwU1tK3), even with `-std=c++11`, so it looks like an Apple thing.